# What does the Sitecore CheckSize Pipeline do?

Tags: sitecore, pipeline, sitecore7

Looking through the web.config of a Sitecore project that we have I can see that there is a Pipeline in the `<uiUpload>` section of the code which is called CheckSize. I am hoping that I can use this to check the size of an item that is being uploaded to Sitecore in order to open a dialog to warn the user of the possible impact of publishing a large file to the site and offer them the opportunity to either back out of the publish or continue.

Does anyone here know what this pipeline does and if I can alter it to perform the checks I have listed above?

```
<uiUpload>
    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckPermissions, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.ResolveFolder, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Done, Sitecore.Kernel" />
</uiUpload>
```

Comment: Just a hint for possible close voters: SiteCore is a high-end CMS and these type of questions can only be asked by or are useful for developers, not for normal users. Migration to Superuser.com is not correct. See also [this MSO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291566/how-to-report-invalid-downvotes)

Comment: @rene thanks rene, I have tagged sitecore but I guess people don't check the tags :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these processors are used when you upload files into Sitecore Media Library.

1. CheckPermissions processor is checking permisions for the folder where you upload files. If you don't have permission is aborting the upload.
2. CheckSize processor is checking if the size of every file uploaded is greater than Media.MaxSizeInDatabase value from web.config.
3. Other 3 processor is resolving the folder where you upload files, add media items and attached the file you upload to media item.

Comment: is there a way for me to replace one of these processors with code that checks if a file is too large and produces a dialog window asking if the users wishes to continue with the upload?

Comment: Yes, you have to rewrite CheckSize processor. Check code for Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize with Reflector or DotPeek and try to to customize it for your requirements.

Comment: I am not seeing any obvious ways in achieving what I have asked in the question, it seems like if I try to insert javascript it will not run, do I need to activate the `SecurityDisabler()` before I try to insert javascript onto the page? Also why the downvote and close vote?